# Best Way To View Who Has Access To A TFS Location?

Tags: tfs, version-control

I am looking for the best way to view the list of users who has access to a specific location in our TFS repository. Let's say we have a location such as $Source\Code\Project1 - how can I see who has read/write access to check in and out of this location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tf permission](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/permission-command) command to list the info. For example:

```
 tf permission /collection:<TeamProjectCollectionUrl> <path in TFS>
```

It will return the detail permission  of the groups such as below picture:
[image]

You can also use `/user:all` option with the command which will return the modified permission for all users under the server path. If you got a result  with `There are no permissions set for this item`. This just mean you didn't set permissions in this path. All permissions are inherited with groups.